# Connective C with ARC relishing objects in background

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, release

Background 
I come from a C background and find giving up manual memory management extremely distressing. The old objective c retain and release model was ok if not a little clumsy.

I have written a osX app that reads data from an unspecified data source with an unknown size and makes a visual presentation of the data. In order to stress the app I generated a very large dataset which generates over a hundred million objects in less that 3 minutes (timing is a guess) but when I tare down the view containing the mutable arrays with hundred million objects the app beach balled while deallocating the objects. I solved this problem by passing the array to a background thread which did the release. Anyway I had to redesign The app so it could be sandboxed and I decided to use ARC and now I am back to the same stress test and the beach balling is back. Is there a way I can get a background thread to do the release of the objects created under ARC or do I need to go back a non ARC design and what if I wanted to re write the app in Swift.

Regards Christian Andersen

Comment: is it possible to show your code how the objects are being allocated?

Comment: There is no fundamental reason why ARC code should behave differently than MRC code - you are just swapping manual insertion of the memory management calls for automatic insertion. Check that you haven't accidentally held onto a reference to your large arrays in your main thread - under MRC that might cause a dangling reference when you release in your background thread, potentially problematic but not if you don't use it, but under ARC such a reference would prevent the deallocation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can get a background thread to do the release of the objects created under ARC

Yes. Just assign nil to the variable on the background thread. But you should ensure that the variable is the only one variable for referring the value.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <pthread.h>

pthread_t g_mainThread;

@interface Test : NSObject
@end

@implementation Test
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Test %p was dealloced on %s", self,
        g_mainThread == pthread_self() ? "the main queue" : "global queue");
}
@end
```

// main

```
int main()
{
    g_mainThread = pthread_self();

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        Test *test = [[Test alloc] init];
        [array addObject:test];
    }

    __block NSMutableArray *arrayOnGlobalQueue = array;

    /*
     * The array object was referenced from *array* and *arrayOnGlobalQueue* variables.
     * The reference count of the array object is 2.
     */

    array = nil;

    /*
     * The *array* variable doesn't refer the array object any more.
     * The reference count of the array object is 1.
     */

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        /*
         * Assign nil to the variable for releasing the array object
         */

        arrayOnGlobalQueue = nil;

        /*
         * The *arrayOnGlobalQueue* variable doesn't refer the array object any more.
         * The reference count of the array object is 0.
         * Thus the array object was dealloced on the background thread(queue).
         */

    });

    dispatch_main();

    return 0;
}
```

The result is this.

```
Test 0x7f96aac033b0 was dealloced on global queue
...
```

But, in common situation, Autorelease Pool refers objects, and Autorelease Pool releases the objects on the main thread.

For instance, if you use NSMutableArray +array class method to instanciate the array object instead of +alloc and -init method,

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
// NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

It means the array object was registered to Autorelease Pool. So, the reference count of the array object is 2. You can avoid the situation using @autoreleasepool.

> do I need to go back a non ARC design

Use `release` under non-ARC instead of assigning null to the variable under ARC.

> what if I wanted to re write the app in Swift

Do exactly the same as Objective-C.

Comment: thanks it is exactly the solution i was looking for and I was kind of close to that solution it just isn't working yet. I am using +alloc -init are you saying I am better of using the +array ?

Comment: that actually works kind of the only problem is that the object that displays the data will not go away until the background tread is done should I pass the array to say my application controller to release the data. the reason I want to release the data in a background thread is so I can clean up the UI and get on with the next presentation without having to wait for for say 18 billion objects to release any sugesstions

Comment: the last message I see is CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces. I will do the obvious the backtrace but I think i need to pass the array to an object that I am not going to tare down

Comment: Wait, you want to release UIView objects on the background thread? UIKit is not thread-safe, so it it not possible.

Comment: No No they are not UIView the are NSStrings in a NSMutableArrays in a NSMutableArray

Comment: Then releasing the array object in the background thread should be fine.